# step definitions in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, cucumber, stub

I have a Rails app that has an Account class which has one or more users related to it; each user has their login credential, but the app always check for the current_account.

I am trying to write a cucumber feature that includes the classic 'given a user is logged in...', and in the steps_definitions file, I need to know how to express the Account class before creating a user object.

Actually, creating the user is no problem, it becomes a problem when I >> 
    click_button 'login'

so... what's the best approach to make sure I have an account (which, by the way, requires a subscription, which requires a subscription plan and all that jazz before they're created...

Comment: have you tried using the 'pickle' gem for more step definitions? https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle